# Removing oneetx.exe

Tags: trojan

So, I accidentally executed an installer downloaded from the web, Avast didn't recognize it as a virus. Nonetheless, by seeing properties I saw it was a network monitoring app, it added a process in my computer "Oneetx.exe".

After searching online I found it was a virus. I localized it inside the Roaming Temp folder. It also configured itself to start on system startup.

I used both, SpyHunter and Malwarebytes to analyse my computer, only SpyHunter detected a threat, and it was the same program, "oneetx.exe" and all files detected where inside Temp folder also.

So I deleted the original downloaded files, forcefully killed the process, and then deleted all files that could be deleted in the Temp folder. Checked for any new programs installed with control panel (nothing there) and emptied the recycle bin. Restarted my computer and re-run SpyHunter, Malwarebytes and Avast, neither detected any threat. I also don't see any oneetx.exe process running. Now I'm going to uninstall Malwarebytes and Spyhunter.

Am I safe now?

Comment: Nobody can guarantee you that you're safe now. If you knew exactly what malware this is, and the malware had been extensively analyzed, and you followed a specific procedure for removing it, then you could be reasonable sure it's gone. But currently you're relying on anti-virus tools (two of which couldn't even detect the malware, indicating this isn't a trivial case) and some manual cleanup. This isn't great. The best solution, as pointed out in mentallurg's link, is to start over with a clean system. Of course that's a lot of work. If this isn't an option, there will always be some risk that

Comment: Yes I wiped the system clean, clean installed from usb and removed old partitions. Thankfully it was a new laptop so there wasnt anything really important there yet.